# How to make FROM and TO filter?

Tags: views

I have a height field for users.

How can I make a simple filter in views where visitors can search to and from?

Like:

Search users: From 150cm To 180cm

Thanks,
Bruno

Comment: i was sure it's a duplicate, but surprisingly I can't find it asked before, not in general way. Nice! It sure should be here, simple thing that's easy... once you know it.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it from views itself from the filter criteria.

[image]

Or if in need of additional options try out the [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters)

> The Better Exposed Filters module replaces the Views' default single-
>   or multi-select boxes with radio buttons or checkboxes, respectively.
>   Description fields and Select All/None links can be added to exposed
>   filters to make for a better user experience

Comment: This works very well, the search can be done "from and to"

However, there is no drop down when entering user details, and then there is no drop down on filter views...

How can I get all of this to work with drop downs, want it to work like the image below:

Thanks
http://pasteboard.co/21usKn1U.png

Comment: Better exposed filters don't work very well , the order doesn't get saved....